# unknown Ammo.btHeightfieldTerrainShape. using ammo.js with npm and webpack in browser. how to initialize ammo properly?

Tags: npm, webpack, ammo.js

I am trying to use ammo.js in a webpack project (es6, target env: browser). I installed "ammo.js" through npm, and added the following configuration to webpack to solve the "fs" unknown module issue:

```
  // Issue: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/6542.
  plugins: [new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/(fs)/)],
```

my problem is at runtime, while trying to use the Ammo.btHeightfieldTerrainShape class, I got a 'undefined' error, while other methods of Ammo seems to be there. 
I am importing Ammo like this:

```
import * as Ammo from 'ammo.js';
```

(and also tried like this: 
    `import Ammo from 'ammo.js';`)

my question is: there is some additional step I am missing in order to initialize the library so the missing class is available? In browsers it seems you have to wait on a promise on the Ammo global method, then use the library, but my required Ammo is an object, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

finally solved.. in case someone else has the same issue: be sure the npm package is installed as:

```
 npm init --save "kripken/ammo.js"
```

I did just:

```
npm init --save ammo.js
```

and that one is not the right repo. That was why it was not up-to-date.
to use with modules, I had to use:

```
import * as Ammo from 'ammo.js';
```